# SAX Parser in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, sax

I am working on a VBA code to parse large xml files.

Initially, I made use of DOM parser but due to memory leak the system hangs and that could not solve my problem.

Now, I turn to using SAX handler as shown in the code below.

I get

> System error: -2146828275

The file is 9GB.

Class Module

Name: clsBook

```vb
Option Explicit

Private mID As Integer
Private mAuthour As String
Private mTitle As String
Private mGenre As String
Private mPrice As String
Private mPublishDate As String
Private mDescription As String

Public Static Property Get ID() As Integer
ID = mID
End Property

Public Static Property Let ID(ByVal vNewValue As Integer)
mID = vNewValue
End Property

Public Static Property Get Authour() As String
Authour = mAuthour
End Property

Public Static Property Let Authour(ByVal vNewValue As String)
mAuthour = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get Title() As String
Title = mTitle
End Property

Public Property Let Title(ByVal vNewValue As String)
mTitle = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get Genre() As String
Genre = mGenre
End Property

Public Property Let Genre(ByVal vNewValue As String)
bGenre = mNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get Price() As String
Price = mPrice
End Property

Public Property Let Price(ByVal vNewValue As String)
mPrice = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get Description() As String
Description = mDescription
End Property

Public Property Let Description(ByVal vNewValue As String)
mDescription = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get PublishedDate() As String
PublishedDate = mPublishDate
End Property

Public Property Let PublishedDate(ByVal vNewValue As String)
mPublishDate = vNewValue
End Property
```

Class Module: ContentHandlerImpl

```vb
Option Explicit

Implements IVBSAXContentHandler

Private lCounter As Long
Private sNodeValues As String
Private bAuthor As Boolean
Private bTitle As Boolean
Private bPrice As Boolean
Private bGenre As Boolean
Private bDescription As Boolean
Private bPublishDate As Boolean
Private mBook As clsBook
Private mBooks As Collection

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_characters(strChars As String)

If (bAuthor) Then
    mBook.Authour = strChars
    bAuthor = False
ElseIf (bTitle) Then
    mBook.Title = strChars
    bTitle = False
ElseIf (bGenre) Then
    mBook.Genre = strChars
    bGenre = False
ElseIf (bPrice) Then
    mBook.Price = strChars
    bPrice = False
ElseIf (bPublishDate) Then
    mBook.PublishedDate = strChars
    bPublishDate = False
ElseIf (bDescription) Then
    mBook.Description = strChars
    bDescription = False
End If

End Sub

Private Property Set IVBSAXContentHandler_documentLocator(ByVal RHS As MSXML2.IVBSAXLocator)

End Property

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_endDocument()

End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_endElement(strNamespaceURI As String, strLocalName As String, strQName As String)

Select Case strLocalName
Case "book"
If mBooks Is Nothing Then
    Set mBooks = New Collection
End If
mBooks.Add (mBook)
If mBook Is Not Nothing Then
    Set mBook = Nothing
End If
Case Else
' do nothing
End Select

End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_endPrefixMapping(strPrefix As String)

End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_ignorableWhitespace(strChars As String)

End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_processingInstruction(strTarget As String, strData As String)

End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_skippedEntity(strName As String)

End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_startDocument()

End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_startElement(strNamespaceURI As String, strLocalName As String, strQName As String, ByVal oAttributes As MSXML2.IVBSAXAttributes)

Select Case strLocalName
Case "book"
    If mBook Is Nothing Then
        Set mBook = New clsBook
    End If
    mBook.ID = CInt(oAttributes.getValueFromName("", "id"))
Case "author"
    bAuthor = True
Case "title"
    bTitle = True
Case "genre"
    bGenre = True
Case "price"
    bPrice = True
Case "publish_date"
    bPublishDate = True
Case "description"
    bDescription = True
Case Else
    ' do nothing
End Select

End Sub

Private Sub IVBSAXContentHandler_startPrefixMapping(strPrefix As String, strURI As String)

End Sub

Public Function getBooks() As Collection
getBooks = mBooks
End Function
```

Test Function

```vb
Sub main()

Dim saxReader As SAXXMLReader60
Dim saxhandler As ContentHandlerImpl
Dim iItems As Collection
Dim iItem As clsBook

Set saxReader = New SAXXMLReader60
Set saxhandler = New ContentHandlerImpl

Set saxReader.contentHandler = saxhandler
saxReader.Parse ThisWorkbook.Path & "\books.xml"

Set iItem = New clsBook
Set iItems = saxhandler.getBooks

For Each iItem In iItems
    Debug.Print "ID: " & iItem.ID & vbCrLf & "Authour: " & iItem.Authour & vbCrLf & "Title: " & iItem.Title & vbCrLf
Next iItem

Set saxReader = Nothing
End Sub


'############Ps find below the point where I am getting the error
Sub main()

Set saxReader = New SAXXMLReader60
Set saxhandler = New ContentHandlerImpl

Set saxReader.contentHandler = saxhandler
saxReader.Parse ThisWorkbook.Path & "\books.xml"

Set saxReader = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific  error you're getting, and where does it occur?

Comment: How large is large? We're engineers, give us numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Error is System error: -2146828275 and the file is 9GB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Man, 9GB, that isn't large, that is huge! The sax parser should be able to handle it but even so it'll most likely be a bit of a stretch.
The first thing I'd suggest is make everything a long, forget about using int.s, esp. in VBA. From memory an int in VB6/VBA is only 60k and change, it ain't gonna cut it.
In fact even long in VB6 is max 2,147,483,647, and if you're doing a count internally for a 9GB file it'll probably pass this so just use double.
Apart form this your machine's memory is going to be the limiting factor.
It's been a while since you posted this - I'm curious as to how you went.